# Parsing changing JSON from API - what design pattern to use - PHP

Tags: php, json, design-patterns

I am getting article/articles from an API. The JSON object varies, some articles have properties that some other do not have.

I need to iterate through the items and manipulate the properties, if they are set.

What is the best way to tackle this?

Actually for now I do something that I find very ugly...

```
foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
  if(isset($item->title)){
     $parsed[$key]['title'] = $this->formatTitle($item->title);
  }
  if(isset($item->salutation)){$parsed[$key]['salutation'] = $item->salutation;}
  if(isset($item->eventDate) && isset($item->enventEndDate)){
     $parsed[$key]['eventDates'] = $this->ersDate($item->eventDate, $item->eventEndDate);
     $parsed[$key]['startDateTimestamp'] = $this->toTimestamp($item->eventDate);
     } elseif(isset($item->eventDate) && !isset($item->enventEndDate)){
     $parsed[$key]['eventDates'] = $this->ersDate($item->eventDate);
     $parsed[$key]['startDateTimestamp'] = $this->toTimestamp($item->eventDate);
      }
```

`//... code continues ...`

Comment: This question may be improved by stating what exactly you mean by "best way"... faster? cleaner looking? shortest? lowest memory usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your source has unpredictable shape, I don't think there is any way around parsing the data.

You can abstract the ugliness in a separate function, so that your main script just does:

```
$parsed = parseAPI($items);
```

If you use `$items = json_decode($apiResponse,true)`, you get an array instead of an object. You can then use the `+` operators on arrays along with a default array to cast all API responses to the same shape.

```
$defaultItem = [
    'salutation' => null,
    'eventDate' => null,
    'eventEndDate' => null,
    ...
];
```

Now when you get items from the API, you can do:

```
$items = json_decode($apiResponse,true);
foreach($items as &$item) $item += $defaultItem;
```

Now each member of `$items` has all the keys you expect. If any key was missing, `$defaultItem`'s matching key and value was inserted.

Comment: Nice. Thank you. Why do you do the loop with the item by reference?

Comment: @Samuel without reference, the changes made to the array (through the loop variable `$item`) will be lost after the loop.  The reference makes the loop variable refer to the actual members of `$items`.  Without it `$item` is just a copy.  If you build your solution based on this answer, don't forget to select and upvote.

Comment: Thank you. Makes sense. 

Yeah I will refactor this way.